# MVC - ICollection within List won't return to Controller on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

In my edit screens I can't seem to get an ICollection within a Model to return to the Controller on POST. For simplicity, there are 2 models, a Pattern table:

```
[Table("Pattern")]
public partial class Pattern
{
    public Pattern()
    {
        PatternFeatureAssociations = new HashSet<PatternFeatureAssociation>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PkID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PatternNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int? CrearedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PatternFeatureAssociation> PatternFeatureAssociations { get; set; }

}
```

And a PatternFeatureAssociation table:

```
[Table("PatternFeatureAssociation")]
public partial class PatternFeatureAssociation
{
    [Key]
    public int PkID { get; set; }

    public int PatternID { get; set; }

    public int FeatureName { get; set; }

    public int FeatureDesc { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Pattern Pattern { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a ViewModel that contains this:

```
public class EditingViewModel
{
    public List<Pattern> patterns { get; set; }

    other values...
}
```

My View (this is a partial version) then goes off from the ViewModel:

```
@model TEST.ViewModels.EditingViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Patterns", FormMethod.Post))
{
<input class="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save Changes" />

<br /><br />

for (int s = 0; s < Model.patterns.Count; s++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PatternNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PkID)

    <p><b>Pattern Number: </b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PatternNumber)</p>

    @foreach (var item in Model.patterns[s].PatternFeatureAssociations)
    { 
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PkID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.PatternID)

        <h3>Feature Name</h3>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FeatureName)</div>

        <h3>Feature Description</h3>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FeatureDesc)</div>               
    }
}  
}
```

However, when I click Save and return to the Controller, the ViewModel doesn't return the PatternFeatureAssociations data. The data does all come through during the GET to the View.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditingViewModel searchedit)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: read [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to index with a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`:

```
     @for(var i = 0; i < Model.patterns[s].PatternFeatureAssociations; i++)
        { 
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PatternFeatureAssociations[i].PkID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PatternFeatureAssociations[i].PatternID)        
            <h3>Feature Name</h3>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.pattern    s[s].PatternFeatureAssociations[i].FeatureName)</div>    
            <h3>Feature Description</h3>
            <div>@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model.patterns[s].PatternFeatureAssociations[i].FeatureDesc)</div>               
    }
```

This will ensure that the relevant inputs are generated with the expected naming convention that the model binder expects.

[**Model Binding To A List**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: If I had a pound for everytime I saw that Haacked article on SO...Great reference hutch.

Comment: @heymega It's the bread and butter of answers. I must admit I've been there though, that's how I know. :)

Comment: @hutchonoid Even when switching to the for loop, it doesn't pull the info back to the controller. I can't directly index the PatterFeatureAssociations. I have to add a .ToList() before I can index [i]. Is it causing an issue because it's an ICollection?

Comment: @Stephanie It needs to be an IList. 

Comment: @hutchonoid If I change it to an IList in the Model, then the line "HashSet<PatternFeatureAssociation>()" complains. Should I just delete that section of the Model?

Comment: @Stephanie, As always, use a view model, not your data model. And you can also use custom a custom `EditTemplate` for typeof `Pattern` and `PatternFeatureAssociation` which simplifies the code and gives you reusable components